# How to resolve UnExpected Subelement

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, apache-axis, savon

I'm trying to call a simple operation with Savon, but it keeps throwing

Savon::SOAPFault ((soapenv:Server) org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement OperationRequest):

Here's my two lines that are throwing this:

client = Savon.client(wsdl: 'http://wsdl_location')
response = client.call(:operation, message: { id: id })

Comment: as you faced this question and I expect that you might found some solutions please share that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means that the message from the remote system is malformed. The message parser encountered an OperationRequest element in the XML when it was expecting something else.

Comment: I see, thank you. If I have no way to manipulate the xml result am I out of luck? I'm simply trying to trigger an operation that is listed when I run client.operations w/ Savon.

Comment: An element named "OperationRequest" suggests that the server is complaining about a malformed message from the client, rather than the client complaining about the response from the server. If you're writing the client, the malformed message could be due to problem in the client code which produces the message. There's not enough detail in your question to troubleshoot exactly what is going wrong.